# Outlook Exchange 2007/2010: is it possible to monitor who or what software is accessing mailbox?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

One of our customers has really strange problem with emails in one of his mailboxes and I was wondering if there is any way of checking who or what software accessed mailbox and did some changes to it? We suspect that evil voodoo is caused by some plugin or software that customer uses but according to them they disabled everything and problem still occurs. So, we really would like to somehow monitor and log any mailbox activity from outside of Outlook itself.

Anybody knows is it even possible to do and with what technology/API/whatever?

**UPDATE:**

I found some article that seems to be recipe for logging such activities with Exchange Security settings: http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/compliance-policies-archiving/exchange-2007-mailbox-access-auditing-part2.html

We will ask customer to setup their server in such way and we'll see if it will help us to gather some info about root of a problem.

But still, if there is any other way to do it or if you know that settings don't work the way I think they are, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use exmon to log all activity and show you the client type.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9a49c22e-e0c7-4b7c-acef-729d48af7bc9&displaylang=en

Comment: thanks for this link, maybe it will hint our admin to some solution